# Strange order of variables written from Write-Host within function

Tags: powershell

With my following code seems Write-Host puts out variables in a strange way (for me coming from C# at least).

Code is here

```
function Run(
[string] $command,
[string] $args
)
{
    Write-Host 'from function - command is:' $command '.args is: ' $args
}

$cmd = "ping"
$args = "208.67.222.222"
Write-Host 'from main - command is:' $cmd '.args is: ' $args
Run("ping","208.67.222.222")
```

Output is here

```
from main - command is: ping .args is:  208.67.222.222
from function - command is: ping 208.67.222.222 .args is:
```

How come `Write-Host` from main works as I expect, but within the function it outputs all variables at the same time? How can I correct this behaviour?

Comment: Actually, your function call is wrong. It should be `Run "ping" "208.67.222.222"`. Function calls in PowerShell do _not_ use parentheses and commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$args in the function is an automatic variable.  It is an array that contains all the arguments passed to the function.

Use something besides $args for your IP address variable.